# Manual printing of bibitems in specific place

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In my thesis, I have a body where I cite different references from my bib file, and at the end they are listed in the bibliography with the corresponding tags. But in addition I need to provide a list of my only my works on a separate page, without tags (so no amsalpha tags of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvfIr.png), [2], ... in front of the work name) and under the "List of the authors papers" title.

For that I wanted to know, how can I just enforce printing an element from my bib file in a particular place from the document. Something like: `\print_bibitem{ilya2018}` etc. Any hints?

**Update:** I have tried using `bibunits`, however the results is as follows

[image]

The code I've used is per `bibunits` manual:

```
\chapter*{List of Publications}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Publications}

\begin{bibunit}[plain]
\cite{tf2018}

\putbib[lit]
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}[amsalpha]
\cite{art2014}
\putbib[lit]
\end{bibunit}
```

Comment: What bibliography package and style do you use? Could you show us a short MWE? There is https://ctan.org/pkg/bibentry which displays the full bibliography entry as a citation. But depending on your setup there could be more elegant methods (think a split bibliography produced with https://ctan.org/pkg/bibunits, https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic, https://ctan.org/pkg/multibib or `biblatex`).

Comment: Please try to provide a full MWE in the sense of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. It would also help if you could explain the desired result in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Use **bibunits** package to sectional bibliography entry. 
Visit: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mcrob/toolbox/latex/bibunits.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that, but unfortunately it does not work as expected yet (please see the updated OP).